# where can i find 5xx error logs , application is running in websphere

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts, websphere

A java application hosted on websphere server is throwing 5xx errors but where to find the logs in server logs or application logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5xx errors are server errors. Hence, do look into server logs. Fifteenth slide of the following link may be of help to you. 
http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038147&aid=1

Answer (score -1):

5xx means the requested resource is not available. Check whether you have the file in the specified location or not.